# hta vbscript read text files, split data and populate drop down box, remove blank option

Tags: drop-down-menu, vbscript, text-files, hta

With the following example there are 3 files.
Executing the dropdownboxtest.hta displays the correct data required in msgboxes.
The issue is the drop down box:

[image: dropdownbox]

The IP data is filled correct and the drop down menu populates correctly (all data present). The issue is that the first option is BLANK and I have tried to make, with this example "colin", the "selected" option using the code:

```
document.getElementById("savedhostname").value = last_hostname_connected_value
```

or

```
document.getElementById("savedhostname").selected = last_hostname_connected_value
```

---

saved_last.cfg

```
last_hostname_connected = "colin"
last_IP_connected = "192.168.1.8"
```

---

savedhosts.txt

```
andy;192.168.1.5
brian;192.168.1.6
colin;192.168.1.8
david;192.168.1.15
eddie;192.168.1.54
```

---

dropdownboxtest.hta

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>      
<head>      
<title>Test Dropdown Box</title>      
<HTA:APPLICATION      
    ID="objHTA_Info"      
    APPLICATIONNAME="Test Dropdown Box"      
    SINGLEINSTANCE="no"    
    SCROLL="no"    
    BORDER="Thin"    
    BorderStyle="Raised"    
    Icon="#"    
    MaximizeButton="No"    
>    
<script language="javascript">    
window.resizeTo (810, 634);    
window.moveTo((screen.width - 10) / 2, (screen.height - 634) / 2);    
</script>    
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">    
Dim last_hostname_connected_value, last_IP_connected_value    
   Sub Window_onLoad    
    With (CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"))    
        Dim objFSO    
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")     
            If .FileExists("saved_last.cfg") Then    
                Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")    
                Set ReadTextFile = FSO.OpenTextFile("saved_last.cfg", 1) ' Open text with read only mode    
                Do Until ReadTextFile.AtEndOfStream    
                Textline = ReadTextFile.Readline()    
                If Instr(Textline, "last_hostname_connected =") Then    
                    last_hostname_connected_value = Split(Textline, "=")(1)    
                    last_hostname_connected_value = Replace(last_hostname_connected_value, Chr(34), "")    
                    last_hostname_connected_value = LTrim(last_hostname_connected_value)    
                    MsgBox "last_hostname_connected_value = " & last_hostname_connected_value                    
                End If     
                If Instr(Textline, "last_IP_connected =") Then    
                    last_IP_connected_value = Split(Textline, "=")(1)    
                    last_IP_connected_value = Replace(last_IP_connected_value, Chr(34), "")    
                    last_IP_connected_value = LTrim(last_IP_connected_value)    
                    MsgBox "last_IP_connected_value : " & last_IP_connected_value                
                End If     
                Loop    
            End If    
    End With    
    Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")   'Creating a File Object    
                Const ForReading = 1                    'Defining Constant Value to read from a file    
                Set obj1 = obj.OpenTextFile("savedhosts.txt", ForReading) 'Opening a text file and reading text from it    
                Dim str,str1,objOption    
                'str=obj1.ReadAll                       'All text from the file is read using ReadAll    
                'Msgbox str                             'Contents of a file will be displayed through message box    
                'Do while obj1.AtEndofStream            'Reading text line wise using Do Loop and ReadLine    
                '   str1=obj1.ReadLine    
                '   Msgbox str1    
                'Loop    
                Call ClearHostnameListbox()    
                Do Until obj1.AtEndOfStream    
                    strNextLine = obj1.ReadLine    
                    arrServiceList = Split(strNextLine, ";")    
                    'MsgBox "arrServiceList(0) = " & arrServiceList(0)    
                    'MsgBox "arrServiceList(1) = " & arrServiceList(1)    
                    Set objOption = document.createElement("OPTION")                        
                        objOption.Text = arrServiceList(0)    
                        objOption.Value = arrServiceList(1)    
                        savedhostname.Add(objOption)    
                        'document.getElementById("savedhostname").value=77747    
                Loop    
                'MsgBox "arrServiceList(0) = " & arrServiceList(0)    
                'MsgBox "arrServiceList(1) = " & arrServiceList(1)    
                obj1.Close                              'Closing a File    
                Set obj=Nothing                         'Releasing File object      
                document.getElementById("savedhostname").value=last_hostname_connected_value    
                MsgBox "End of SUB check last_hostname_connected_value = " & last_hostname_connected_value
                document.getElementById("IP-Input").value = last_IP_connected_value    
    End Sub    
</script>    
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">    
    Sub ClearHostnameListbox()    
        For Each objOption in savedhostname.Options    
         objOption.RemoveNode    
         Next    
    End Sub    
</script>       
</head>    
<body>    
TEST    
<br>    
IP: <input type='text' maxlength="15" class="enterhostip" size=22 id="IP-Input" name="hostname_IP" />    
<br>    
Saved Name : <select id="savedhostname" selected="savedhostname" maxlength="20" name="savedhostname" class="savedhostname" value=""></select>    
</body>    
</html>
```

Clearly there is something going on here that I cannot seem to pin down, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the default value in a select, you can do this by adding the `selected` attribute to the specific `<option>`, eg

```html
<select>
  <option value=1>1</option>
  <option value=2 selected>2</option>
</select>
```

so, in your loop you would set the attribute

```vb
Set objOption = document.createElement("OPTION")                        
objOption.Text = arrServiceList(0)    
objOption.Value = arrServiceList(1)

if objOption.Value = last_IP_selected then
    objOption.setAttribute "selected", "selected"
end if
```

This assumes that all `objOption.Value`s are unique.

Comment: As I have listed the text and values are different. How do I extract the Text from the Value?
is it as follows?

`If objOption.Text = hostname`

I am trying to capture the Text and place it into another field also updating the saved_last.cfg file.

Comment: I thought the issue you were having (from `The issue is that the first option is BLANK and I have tried to make, with this example "colin", the "selected" option using the code:`) was that you couldn't set a particular value as the initial selection in the combobox?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I already gave a messy answer some days ago to eliminate the blank line. Should I start another question? I'm trying to learn this code and logic. 

'objOption.setAttribute "selected", "selected"' isnt working properly, not sure why.

As i'm giving parts of the code from a testbed and not the full working code, it may be quite confusing to incorporate it all fully. I am keen to learn though so very much appreciate your help now and in the past!

Comment: Also, aren't combo box, drop down menu, drop down box all the same thing ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>      
<head>      
<title>Test Dropdown Box</title>      
<HTA:APPLICATION      
ID="objHTA_Info"      
APPLICATIONNAME="Test Dropdown Box"      
SINGLEINSTANCE="no"    
SCROLL="no"    
BORDER="Thin"    
BorderStyle="Raised"    
Icon="#"    
MaximizeButton="No"    
>    
<script language="javascript">    
window.resizeTo (810, 634);    
window.moveTo((screen.width - 10) / 2, (screen.height - 634) / 2);    
</script>    
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">    
Dim last_hostname_connected_value, last_IP_connected_value    
Sub Window_onLoad    
    With (CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"))    
        Dim objFSO    
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")     
        If .FileExists("saved_last.cfg") Then    
            Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")    
            Set ReadTextFile = FSO.OpenTextFile("saved_last.cfg", 1) ' Open text with read only mode    
            Do Until ReadTextFile.AtEndOfStream    
                Textline = ReadTextFile.Readline()    
                If Instr(Textline, "last_hostname_connected =") Then    
                    last_hostname_connected_value = Split(Textline, "=")(1)    
                    last_hostname_connected_value = Replace(last_hostname_connected_value, Chr(34), "")    
                    last_hostname_connected_value = LTrim(last_hostname_connected_value)    
'MsgBox "last_hostname_connected_value = " & last_hostname_connected_value                    
                End If     
                If Instr(Textline, "last_IP_connected =") Then    
                    last_IP_connected_value = Split(Textline, "=")(1)    
                    last_IP_connected_value = Replace(last_IP_connected_value, Chr(34), "")    
                    last_IP_connected_value = LTrim(last_IP_connected_value)    
'MsgBox "last_IP_connected_value : " & last_IP_connected_value                
                End If     
            Loop    
        End If    
    End With    
    Call ClearHostnameListbox() 
    Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")   'Creating a File Object    
    Const ForReading = 1                    'Defining Constant Value to read from a file    
    Set obj1 = obj.OpenTextFile("savedhosts.txt", ForReading) 'Opening a text file and reading text from it    
    Dim str,str1,objOption    
'str=obj1.ReadAll                       'All text from the file is read using ReadAll    
'Msgbox str                             'Contents of a file will be displayed through message box    
'Do while obj1.AtEndofStream            'Reading text line wise using Do Loop and ReadLine    
'   str1=obj1.ReadLine    
'   Msgbox str1    
'Loop       
    Do Until obj1.AtEndOfStream    
        strNextLine = obj1.ReadLine    
        arrServiceList = Split(strNextLine, ";")    
'MsgBox "arrServiceList(0) = " & arrServiceList(0)    
'MsgBox "arrServiceList(1) = " & arrServiceList(1)    
        Set objOption = document.createElement("OPTION")                        
        objOption.Text = arrServiceList(0)    
        objOption.Value = arrServiceList(1)    
        savedhostname.Add(objOption)    
'document.getElementById("savedhostname").value=77747    
    Loop    
'MsgBox "arrServiceList(0) = " & arrServiceList(0)    
'MsgBox "arrServiceList(1) = " & arrServiceList(1)    
    obj1.Close                              'Closing a File    
    Set obj=Nothing                         'Releasing File object      
'document.getElementById("savedhostname").value=last_hostname_connected_value    
'MsgBox "End of SUB check last_hostname_connected_value = " & last_hostname_connected_value
    document.getElementById("IP-Input").value = last_IP_connected_value    
End Sub 
Sub ClearHostnameListbox()    
    For Each objOption in savedhostname.Options    
        objOption.RemoveNode    
    Next    
End Sub     
</script>       
</head>    
<body>    
TEST    
<br>    
IP: <input type='text' maxlength="15" class="enterhostip" size=22 id="IP-Input" name="hostname_IP" />    
<br>    
Saved Name : <select id="savedhostname" selected="savedhostname" maxlength="20" name="savedhostname" class="savedhostname"></select>    
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Removing the `value=""` I already tried. Although this results in the removal of the blank line now it just displays the first option "andy" instead of the desired "colin".

Answer (score 0):

The following messy code works but fails for one reason.

Working:

- Upon loading it uses the last known Name/IP and populates the IP text and Name accordingly.
- The blank line is gone
- Choosing another value from the drop down box automatically changes the IP text field.
- The value of the IP is written correctly to the "saved_last.cfg" file.

Not working:

- The value of the Host name it writes to "saved_last.cfg" is not desired.
  When you choose from the dropdown menu it writes the IP address to the "last_hostname_connected_value" instead of the Host name.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>    
    <html>      
    <head>      
    <title>Test Dropdown Box</title>      
    <HTA:APPLICATION      
        ID="objHTA_Info"      
        APPLICATIONNAME="Test Dropdown Box"      
        SINGLEINSTANCE="no"    
        SCROLL="no"    
        BORDER="Thin"    
        BorderStyle="Raised"    
        Icon="#"    
        MaximizeButton="No"    
    >    
    <script language="javascript">    
    window.resizeTo (810, 634);    
    window.moveTo((screen.width - 10) / 2, (screen.height - 634) / 2);    
    </script>    
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">    
    Dim last_hostname_connected_value, last_IP_connected_value    
       Sub Window_onLoad
       'MsgBox "Start of SUB check last_hostname_connected_value = " & last_hostname_connected_value    
        With (CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"))    
            Dim objFSO    
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")     
                If .FileExists("saved_last.cfg") Then    
                    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")    
                    Set ReadTextFile = FSO.OpenTextFile("saved_last.cfg", 1) ' Open text with read only mode    
                    Do Until ReadTextFile.AtEndOfStream    
                    Textline = ReadTextFile.Readline()    
                    If Instr(Textline, "last_hostname_connected =") Then    
                        last_hostname_connected_value = Split(Textline, "=")(1)    
                        last_hostname_connected_value = Replace(last_hostname_connected_value, Chr(34), "")    
                        last_hostname_connected_value = LTrim(last_hostname_connected_value)    
                        'MsgBox "last_hostname_connected_value = " & last_hostname_connected_value                    
                    End If     
                    If Instr(Textline, "last_IP_connected =") Then    
                        last_IP_connected_value = Split(Textline, "=")(1)    
                        last_IP_connected_value = Replace(last_IP_connected_value, Chr(34), "")    
                        last_IP_connected_value = LTrim(last_IP_connected_value)    
                        'MsgBox "last_IP_connected_value : " & last_IP_connected_value                
                    End If     
                    Loop    
                End If    
        End With    
        Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")   'Creating a File Object    
                    Const ForReading = 1                    'Defining Constant Value to read from a file    
                    Set obj1 = obj.OpenTextFile("savedhosts.txt", ForReading) 'Opening a text file and reading text from it    
                    Dim str,str1,objOption    
                    'str=obj1.ReadAll                       'All text from the file is read using ReadAll    
                    'Msgbox str                             'Contents of a file will be displayed through message box    
                    'Do while obj1.AtEndofStream            'Reading text line wise using Do Loop and ReadLine    
                    '   str1=obj1.ReadLine    
                    '   Msgbox str1    
                    'Loop    
                    Call ClearHostnameListbox()    
                    Do Until obj1.AtEndOfStream    
                        strNextLine = obj1.ReadLine    
                        arrServiceList = Split(strNextLine, ";")    
                        'MsgBox "arrServiceList(0) = " & arrServiceList(0)    
                        'MsgBox "arrServiceList(1) = " & arrServiceList(1)    
                        Set objOption = document.createElement("OPTION")                        
                            objOption.Text = arrServiceList(0)    
                            objOption.Value = arrServiceList(1)    
                            OptionChooser = last_hostname_connected_value
                            savedhostname.Add(objOption)    
                            'document.getElementById("savedhostname").select=77747    
                    Loop    
                    'MsgBox "arrServiceList(0) = " & arrServiceList(0)    
                    'MsgBox "arrServiceList(1) = " & arrServiceList(1)    
                    obj1.Close                              'Closing a File    
                    Set obj=Nothing                         'Releasing File object
                    'MsgBox "1PreEnd of SUB check last_hostname_connected_value = " & last_hostname_connected_value
                    'last_hostname_connected_value=document.getElementById("savedhostname").value  
                    'document.getElementById("savedhostname").value=last_hostname_connected_value 
                    'MsgBox "2PreEnd of SUB check last_hostname_connected_value = " & last_hostname_connected_value   
                    'document.getElementById("savedhostname").selected=david
                    'MsgBox "End of SUB check last_hostname_connected_value = " & last_hostname_connected_value
                    document.getElementById("IP-Input").value = last_IP_connected_value  
                    'document.getElementById("IP-Input").value = last_hostname_connected_value    
                 'document.getElementById("savedhostname").selected = last_hostname_connected_value    
          document.getElementById("savedhostname").value = last_IP_connected_value
      End Sub    
    </script>    
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">    
        Sub ClearHostnameListbox()    
            For Each objOption in savedhostname.Options    
             objOption.RemoveNode    
             Next    
        End Sub    
        Sub changeNamechangeIP
      last_hostname_connected_value=document.getElementById("savedhostname").value
      'MsgBox "last_hostname_connected_value = " & last_hostname_connected_value
      last_IP_connected_value=document.getElementById("IP-Input").value
      'MsgBox "last_IP_connected_value = " & last_IP_connected_value
      Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Const ForReading = 1
            Const ForWriting = 2
            Dim myFile,myTemp,objFSO,objFile,strText,strNewText,objRegEx
            Set myFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("saved_last.cfg", ForReading, True)
      Set myTemp= objFSO.OpenTextFile("saved_last.cfg" & ".tmp", ForWriting, True)
        Do While Not myFile.AtEndofStream
        myLine = myFile.ReadLine
       If InStr(myLine, "last_IP_connected = ") Then
         myLine = "last_IP_connected = " & Chr(34) & last_hostname_connected_value & Chr(34)
        End If
        If InStr(myLine, "last_hostname_connected = ") Then
         myLine = "last_hostname_connected = " & Chr(34) & last_hostname_connected_value & Chr(34)
         End If
       myTemp.WriteLine myLine
      Loop
      myFile.Close
      myTemp.Close
      objFSO.DeleteFile("saved_last.cfg")
      objFSO.MoveFile "saved_last.cfg" & ".tmp", "saved_last.cfg"
      With (CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"))    
            'Dim objFSO    
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")     
                If .FileExists("saved_last.cfg") Then    
                    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")    
                    Set ReadTextFile = FSO.OpenTextFile("saved_last.cfg", 1) ' Open text with read only mode    
                    Do Until ReadTextFile.AtEndOfStream    
                    Textline = ReadTextFile.Readline()    
                    If Instr(Textline, "last_hostname_connected =") Then    
                        last_hostname_connected_value = Split(Textline, "=")(1)    
                        last_hostname_connected_value = Replace(last_hostname_connected_value, Chr(34), "")    
                        last_hostname_connected_value = LTrim(last_hostname_connected_value)    
                        'MsgBox "last_hostname_connected_value = " & last_hostname_connected_value                    
                    End If     
                    If Instr(Textline, "last_IP_connected =") Then    
                        last_IP_connected_value = Split(Textline, "=")(1)    
                        last_IP_connected_value = Replace(last_IP_connected_value, Chr(34), "")    
                        last_IP_connected_value = LTrim(last_IP_connected_value)    
                        'MsgBox "last_IP_connected_value : " & last_IP_connected_value                
                    End If     
                    Loop    
                End If    
         End With    
        Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")   'Creating a File Object    
                    'Const ForReading = 1                    'Defining Constant Value to read from a file    
                    Set obj1 = obj.OpenTextFile("savedhosts.txt", ForReading) 'Opening a text file and reading text from it    
                    Dim str,str1,objOption    
                    'str=obj1.ReadAll                       'All text from the file is read using ReadAll    
                    'Msgbox str                             'Contents of a file will be displayed through message box    
                    'Do while obj1.AtEndofStream            'Reading text line wise using Do Loop and ReadLine    
                    '   str1=obj1.ReadLine    
                    '   Msgbox str1    
                    'Loop    
                    Call ClearHostnameListbox()    
                    Do Until obj1.AtEndOfStream    
                        strNextLine = obj1.ReadLine    
                        arrServiceList = Split(strNextLine, ";")    
                        'MsgBox "arrServiceList(0) = " & arrServiceList(0)    
                        'MsgBox "arrServiceList(1) = " & arrServiceList(1)    
                        Set objOption = document.createElement("OPTION")                        
                            objOption.Text = arrServiceList(0)    
                            objOption.Value = arrServiceList(1)    
                            OptionChooser = last_hostname_connected_value
                            savedhostname.Add(objOption)    
                            'document.getElementById("savedhostname").select=77747    
                    Loop    
                    'MsgBox "arrServiceList(0) = " & arrServiceList(0)    
                    'MsgBox "arrServiceList(1) = " & arrServiceList(1)    
                    obj1.Close                              'Closing a File    
                    Set obj=Nothing                         'Releasing File object
                    'MsgBox "1PreEnd of SUB check last_hostname_connected_value = " & last_hostname_connected_value
                    'last_hostname_connected_value=document.getElementById("savedhostname").value  
                    'document.getElementById("savedhostname").value=last_hostname_connected_value 
                    'MsgBox "2PreEnd of SUB check last_hostname_connected_value = " & last_hostname_connected_value   
                    'document.getElementById("savedhostname").selected=david
                    'MsgBox "End of SUB check last_hostname_connected_value = " & last_hostname_connected_value
                    document.getElementById("IP-Input").value = last_IP_connected_value  
                    'document.getElementById("IP-Input").value = last_hostname_connected_value    
                 'document.getElementById("savedhostname").selected = last_hostname_connected_value    
          document.getElementById("savedhostname").value = last_IP_connected_value
      End Sub    
    </script>  
    <style>
    select > option[value=""] {
        display: none;
    }
    </style>
    </head>    
    <body>    
    TEST    
    <br>    
    IP: <input type='text' maxlength="15"  class="enterhostip" size=22 id="IP-Input" name="hostname_IP" />    
    <br>    
    Saved Name : <select id="savedhostname" onchange="vbscript:changeNamechangeIP" ></select>    
    <br>
    </body>    
    </html>
```